# Unity Google Play Games Services Plugin use in Debug

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I want to debug Google Play Games Services with Unity, but if i directly press play and debug with a connected USB Android Device, it won't work.
I have to build it everytime, which slows down the development process massively. Is there a way to directly test Google Play Games Services without building the app everytime?

Answer (score 0):

There is an app [Unity Remote 5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unity3d.mobileremote) through which you can debug and test your app locally through USB.

The official documentation of this could be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html).

Comment: Thank you, but that wasn't the question. I was asking to debug with Google Play Services since it seems I have to build them, to make Google Services possible. If i directly press Play and debug using USB, it uses a different package and the google play services won't work. I want to avoid building the app everytime, but couldn't find a way to do so.